# Checking for negative values with scanner in

Tags: java

I have just written my first java program for a class I am taking which is used to give a student graduation information based on the credits for each class remaining.  I have gotten everything to work except the required entry to check for negative values.  Please see below and let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
package txp1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class txp1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Welcome to the University Graduation Calculator!");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("This calculator will help determine how many terms "
                + "you have remaining and your tuition total based upon credits"
                + " completed per semester.");

        System.out.println();

        double tuitionpersem = 2890;

        System.out.println("We will begin by entering the number of credits for"
                + " each class remaining toward your degree.");

        double sum = 0;

        ArrayList<Double> credit = new ArrayList<>();

        {

            System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits for each individual class on a separate line and then press enter, Q to quit:");

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            double number = 0;
            number = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if (number <= 0);
            {
                System.out.println("The number of credits must be greater than zero!");
            }

            while (in.hasNextDouble()) {

                credit.add(in.nextDouble());

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < credit.size(); i++) {

                sum += credit.get(i);

            }

            System.out.println("Total credits remaining: " + sum);

        }

        int perterm = 0;

        System.out.println("How many credits do you plan to take per term? ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        perterm = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if (perterm <= 0);
        {
            System.out.println("The number of credits must be greater than zero!");
        }
        double totterms = sum / perterm;

        totterms = Math.ceil(totterms);

        System.out.print("Your remaining terms: ");

        System.out.println(totterms);

        double terms = (totterms);

        System.out.print("The number of months to complete at this rate is: ");

        System.out.println(6 * terms);

        double cost = terms * 2890;

        System.out.println("The cost to complete at this rate is: " + cost);

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error message or issue?

Comment: You should make sure to provide a proper question and / or an error. This makes the debug / answering process and at least your user experience better.

Answer (score 4):

```
double number = 0;
number = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
if (number <= 0);
```

The ";" at the end of if statement is the end of it. You are not doing anything with the result of number <=0. I believe you meant it to be like:

```
if (number <= 0){
   //operations….
}
```

Notice that you create number of type double, then assign an int (parsed from String) to it. You can use nextDouble method to get a double directly, and if you plan this number to be an Integer anyway then use type int instead of double and nextInt instead of parsing. For more information about parsing from input, check Scanner [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements terminate if you put a semi colon at the end of them. Effectively ending your logic right there. The program basically checks the condition and then moves on. Which in turn executes your second statement regardless of what number <= 0 resolves to.

```
 //Does not get expected results
    if (number <= 0);
    {
        //Gets executed regardless of condition
        System.out.println("The number of credits must be greater than zero!");
    }

//Gets expected results
    if (number <= 0)
    {
        //Gets executed only if the condition returns true
        System.out.println("The number of credits must be greater than zero!");
    }
```

Edit: Changed due to some helpful input.

2nd Edit: I would also consider putting a loop in your code that makes the user re-enter input to get the desired value. If you put in a negative value your code will just spit the error message and keep running which can make you scratch your head. Unless your teacher isn't grading on that then forget all of what I just said. =p

Comment: Thank you both very much!! That was extremely helpful and is now working :)

Comment: Yes, I just tried the code without the semicolons and its working. I am now trying to setup the loop. The grade is on a point system so I am trying get it as close to working correctly as possible so it will pass.

Comment: If you add the loop and account for most cases of human error* you should be fine.

*Human error being inputting a negative value where a positive one was expected, or a letter where a numeric value was expected. I'm not sure how strict your teacher is but I would consider adding solutions to those problems as well.

Comment: Ahhh thank you.  The assignment specifies checking for negative numbers so I will make sure at least that part is working fine.